# COORS error while using Geocoding API in Angular app

Tags: angular, api, geocoding

I need lat, long of an address so i use :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,
+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

with my API Key

I have made this request from service in angular client
Response is :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at....has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Answer (score -1):

I think problem is that your request contains `Authorization` header. CORS error which you posted says:

> Request header field **authorization** is **not allowed** by **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** in preflight response.

So the API does not allow `Authorization` header to be sent in your request. You should probably do authorization only by API key in query param, as you posted.

**Additional details:** [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) of a preflight response specify which headers are allowed in your CORS request. If your request contains headers, which are not specified there, you will get CORS error.

Comment: this is the function which is requesting

Comment: async getLatLong(){
    let coord = await this.http.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,
      +Mountain+View,+CA&key=API_KEY&libraries=places`).toPromise();
      console.log(coord)
  }

Comment: Open developer tools and check the `Request` headers, if it contains Authorization header, it can be added e.g. by interceptor.

Comment: General => Request URL => Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin.   Request Headers => Authorization: Bearer....

Comment: yep, there you go, there is `Authorization: Bearer....` header in the request. This is causing the CORS error.

Comment: how to fix it? how do I remove this error  permanently

Comment: There have to be place in your code where is header added to the request. Search for `Authorization` in your code. This kind of info is tend to be added for every request, so you might have a look for interceptor, which can add this header for all requests issued in your application.

Comment: @ChoudaryUsamaAbbas if this answer helped you, please consider accepting and upvoting it.